# Rust lifetime scoping in structs

Tags: rust, lifetime-scoping

So, I'm working on porting a string tokenizer that I wrote in Python over to Rust, and I've run into an issue I can't seem to get past with lifetimes and structs.

So, the process is basically:

1. Get an array of files
2. Convert each file to a `Vec<String>` of tokens
3. User a `Counter` and `Unicase` to get counts of individual instances of tokens from each `vec`
4. Save that count in a struct, along with some other data
5. (Future) do some processing on the set of Structs to accumulate the total data along side the per-file data

```rust
struct Corpus<'a> {
    words: Counter<UniCase<&'a String>>,
    parts: Vec<CorpusPart<'a>>
}

pub struct CorpusPart<'a> {
    percent_of_total: f32,
    word_count: usize,
    words: Counter<UniCase<&'a String>>
}

fn process_file(entry: &DirEntry) -> CorpusPart {
    let mut contents = read_to_string(entry.path())
        .expect("Could not load contents.");

    let tokens = tokenize(&mut contents);
    let counted_words = collect(&tokens);

    CorpusPart {
        percent_of_total: 0.0,
        word_count: tokens.len(),
        words: counted_words
    }
}

pub fn tokenize(normalized: &mut String) -> Vec<String> {
    // snip ...
}

pub fn collect(results: &Vec<String>) -> Counter<UniCase<&'_ String>> {
    results.iter()
        .map(|w| UniCase::new(w))
        .collect::<Counter<_>>()
}
```

However, when I try to return `CorpusPart` it complains that it is trying to reference a local variable `tokens`. How can/should I deal with this? I tried adding lifetime annotations, but couldn't figure it out...

Essentially, I no longer need the `Vec<String>`, but I do need some of the `String`s that were in it for the counter.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can we get a nearly compilable version of your code snippet (i.e. where the only error is the lifetime)? Though at a glance I believe you can just take out the String reference in `CorpusPart` (and most of the other string references), since you no longer need the old Vec. I'll post a proper answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are throwing away `Vec<String>`, but still referencing the elements inside it. If you no longer need `Vec<String>`, but still require some of the contents inside, you have to transfer the ownership to something else.

I assume you want `Corpus` and `CorpusPart` to both point to the same Strings, so you are not duplicating Strings needlessly. If that is the case, either `Corpus` or `CorpusPart` must own the String, so that the one that don't own the String references the Strings owned by the other. (Sounds more complicated that it actually is)

I will assume `CorpusPart` owns the String, and `Corpus` just points to those strings

```
use std::fs::DirEntry;
use std::fs::read_to_string;

pub struct UniCase<a> {
    test: a
}

impl<a> UniCase<a> {
    fn new(item: a) -> UniCase<a> {
        UniCase {
            test: item
        }
    }
}

type Counter<a> = Vec<a>;

struct Corpus<'a> {
    words: Counter<UniCase<&'a String>>, // Will reference the strings in CorpusPart (I assume you implemented this elsewhere)
    parts: Vec<CorpusPart>
}

pub struct CorpusPart {
    percent_of_total: f32,
    word_count: usize,
    words: Counter<UniCase<String>> // Has ownership of the strings
}

fn process_file(entry: &DirEntry) -> CorpusPart {
    let mut contents = read_to_string(entry.path())
        .expect("Could not load contents.");

    let tokens = tokenize(&mut contents);
    let length = tokens.len(); // Cache the length, as tokens will no longer be valid once passed to collect
    let counted_words = collect(tokens);

    CorpusPart {
        percent_of_total: 0.0,
        word_count: length,
        words: counted_words
    }
}

pub fn tokenize(normalized: &mut String) -> Vec<String> {
    Vec::new()
}

pub fn collect(results: Vec<String>) -> Counter<UniCase<String>> {
    results.into_iter() // Use into_iter() to consume the Vec that is passed in, and take ownership of the internal items
        .map(|w| UniCase::new(w))
        .collect::<Counter<_>>()
}
```

I aliased `Counter<a>` to `Vec<a>`, as I don't know what Counter you are using.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=48e8581586fda440832e29243a62866d)

Comment: This solved my issue, obviously I don't have a firm grasp of ownership yet. Thanks a lot for the useful comments on `into_iter` and `let length...` that clarified things a lot for me. Sorry I wasn't able to get you a minimal code sample, but it seems you figured it out!